# Flash message requires a redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, connect-flash

```
"connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
"cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
"ejs": "^2.4.2",
"express": "^4.14.0",
"express-session": "^1.13.0",
```

I wrote this post request to check whether an existing username or email exist and if so it will flash a message saying either the username or the email is taken. If nothing is taken it will save the data and put it into a database. My question is, in order for me to flash the message "the username is taken" or "That email is taken", I have to call `usernameFlash(); res.redirect('/')`. This requires me to redirect back to the homepage which takes the purpose out of telling the user if their email or username is taken. How could I flash the message without calling for a redirect in this scenario.

```
app.post('/signup', function(req, res) {

function usernameFlash(){
  req.flash('messages', 'That username is taken.');
}

function emailFlash(){
  req.flash('messages', 'That email is taken.');
}


var userDetails = User({
    firstname: req.body.firstname,
    username: req.body.username,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password1, bcrypt.genSaltSync(10))
});

User.findOne({
    $or: [ { 'username': req.body.username}, {'email': req.body.email}]
}, function(err, user) {
    if (user) {
        if(user.username === req.body.username){
          usernameFlash();
          res.redirect('/')
        } else {
        }
        if(user.email === req.body.email){
          emailFlash();
          res.redirect('/')
        } else {
        }
    } else {
      userDetails.save(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
      });
      res.redirect('/');
      console.log('change to login')
    }
    if (err) {
        return done(err);
    }
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could send flash messages to one specific page like this:

```
res.render("/user/login", { messages: req.flash("info", "That email is taken") } );
```

so in your case if your current page is "/login" , you should send the response to the same page and you will see the message, if you want to keep the form data, you could send back the form data like this:

```
res.render("/user/login", { email: req.body.email, messages: req.flash("info", "That email is taken") } );
```

and then use the variable email in your template.